# Malloc error: double free in OBJC

Tags: iphone

I'm working with an array of NSNumbers, and i have a method to fill them based on the button pressed;

```
 - (NSMutableArray *)addNumberToArray:(int)numPressed andWithGuessArray:(NSMutableArray *)guessArray andWithActiveIndex:(int)activeIndex {
NSNumber *numberPressed = [NSNumber numberWithInt:numPressed];
switch (numPressed) {
    case 1:
        [guessArray replaceObjectAtIndex:activeIndex withObject:numberPressed];
        break;

    case 2:
        [guessArray replaceObjectAtIndex:activeIndex withObject:numberPressed];
        break;

    case 3:
        [guessArray replaceObjectAtIndex:activeIndex withObject:numberPressed];
        break;

    case 4:
        [guessArray replaceObjectAtIndex:activeIndex withObject:numberPressed];
        break;

    case 5:
        [guessArray replaceObjectAtIndex:activeIndex withObject:numberPressed];
        break;

    case 6:
        [guessArray replaceObjectAtIndex:activeIndex withObject:numberPressed];
        break;

    case 7:
        [guessArray replaceObjectAtIndex:activeIndex withObject:numberPressed];
        break;

    case 8:
        [guessArray replaceObjectAtIndex:activeIndex withObject:numberPressed];
        break;

    case 9:
        [guessArray replaceObjectAtIndex:activeIndex withObject:numberPressed];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
[numberPressed release];

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%i",[[guessArray objectAtIndex:i]intValue]);
}
NSLog(@"----");

return guessArray;
```

}

Then i have a method to delete all the numbers in the array.

```
- (void)deleteAll:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"%@",guessArray);
for (int i = 0; i < numbersInAns; i++) {
    [guessArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];

}

activeIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%i",[[guessArray objectAtIndex:i]intValue]);
}
```

}

The problem occurs when i fill the array, clear it, fill it again, and try to clear it again.

2011-03-19 13:58:43.492 BombDefusal[4711:207] (
    2,
    2,
    3,
    3
) //this is whats in the array right before its cleared, these are all NSNumbers

BombDefusal(4711,0xa096a540) malloc: *** error for object 0x4e0cc40: double free
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

(gdb) print-object 0x4e0cc40

2

*Solved*

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but why are you using a switch rather than a single if statement?

Comment: Haha it used to be a necessary switch, but i changed it, but i didnt notice it was now extra code

Answer (score 2):

The error message you're getting says "set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug".  Did you try that?

You're calling `release` on the `numberPressed` object, but you didn't ever `retain` it.  The `NSNumber` class method `numberWithInt:` returns an autoreleased object to you.  That `release` call is unnecessary and incorrect.

Besides that, *every* entry in your switch statement contains *exactly* the same code - why did you write the switch statement at all?  You could replace that whole block with just the one line:

```
[guessArray replaceObjectAtIndex:activeIndex withObject:numberPressed];
```

Comment: Oh haha yeah, it used to have some different code in it that needed a switch but i made it better, and i didnt notice i didnt need the switch